# R administration

Tags: r, ubuntu-16.04

I have 2 R installations in Ubuntu 16.04. One is in `/usr/local/bin/R` 
and the other one is in `/usr/bin/R`. The former is the default one. I want to make the latter default.

Answer (score 1):

The following are if you are using `bash` shell.

You need to update the `PATH` variable. In the terminal, you can enter the following command :

```
export PATH=/usr/bin:$PATH
```

To make it permanent, you need to add this line at the end of your `.bashrc` file.

Comment: it worked, thanks. But can you explain what is happening?

Comment: `PATH` is a bash variable that contains paths to directories. You can see them by entering `echo $PATH`. All the executables (like R) that are in a directory listed in PATH are directly accessible from anywhere. That is why you can just type `R` or `python` to start a interactive session no matter the current working directory. By moving `/usr/bin` in first position in PATH, you ensure that the version of R that you use is the one from `/usr/bin`. Do not hesitate to accept the answer if it worked, thanks.